# what to put in netbeans 17 phpunit field for skeleton-generator

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

phpunit-skeleton-generator was apparently discontinued 9-10 years ago. Netbeans released v17 this year still with a field in the php testing dialog to locate the skelgen template, so I presume they expect users to still put something in this field, but what?

I have tried with using the phpunit-skelgen file. This appears to run but then returns an error because it cannot find "Text_Template".

Is there something else I should be using to automatically build phpunit tests, or is the whole concept of doing this irretrievably flawed?